# Replacing floats in a string with a number (python)

Tags: python, regex, string, floating-point

I have a list with strings containing floats:

```
test_number = ['8.3','10.0','1.0','8.7','6.9','4.7','8.7']
```

I want to replace these floats with two categories: either '1' for every number up to 5.9 and '2' for every number between 6.0 and 10.0. Since it are strings, I tried using regular expressions to find the numbers:

```
test5=[]
for r in test_number:
    if re.match("[0-5]?[.][0-9]",r): #for every number up till 5.9
        test5.append(1)
    if re.match("[6-9]?[.][0-9]",r): #for every number from 6.0 till 9.9
        test5.append(2)
    if re.match("[0-1]?[0-1]?[.][0-9]?",r): #for every 10 (now a 3 for more clear output)
        test5.append(3)
```

This returned the following output:

```
test5
[2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2]
```

As you can see, this does not return what I want.

I also tried using pandas pd.cut:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(['8.3','10.0','1.0','8.7','6.9','4.7','8.7'])
df_test.columns=['rating']

bins = [0.1, 5.9, 10.0]
group_names = [1,2]
df_test['number'] = pd.cut(df_test['number'], bins, labels=group_names)
```

Which gave me only 1's. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what about numbers between 5.9 and 6.0 ?

Comment: Good point. Since I do not have number between 5.9 and 6.0, I figured this wouldn't be a problem. Do you have suggestions for when there are numbers between 5.9 and 6.0?

Comment: why not setting 1 for < 6.0 and forget about 5.9?

Comment: Oops.. did not even consider that. Thanks for pointing this out to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in your case is that the last expression `if re.match("[0-1]?[0-1]?[.][0-9]?",r)` matches `10.0` and `1.0` and you didn't use `elif` (also, regex is wrong, it should probably be `re.match("10[.][0-9]?",r)`)

In this particular case, you don't need regex, regexes are best for string match.
Anything with number computation leads to and cornercases, what if the numbers are in scientific notation for instance?

So, just convert to float and compare using a nested ternary comparison in a list comprehension (note that with your specification the 5.9=>6.0 range will yield `3` which is probably not what you want):

```
test_number = ['8.3','10.0','1.0','8.7','6.9','4.7','8.7']


test5 = [1 if float(x)<=5.9 else 2 if 6.0 <= float(x) < 10.0 else 3 for x in test_number]

print(test5)
```

result:

```
[2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
```

slight drawback here: I compute `float(x)` twice. Can be improved by nesting a generator comprehension or merely `map` to `float`:

```
test5 = [1 if x<=5.9 else 2 if 6.0 <= x < 10.0 else 3 for x in map(float,test_number)]
```

note that a more logical solution would be to include the 5.9=>6.0 range in the first case:

```
test5 = [1 if x<6.0 else 2 if x < 10.0 else 3 for x in map(float,test_number)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple imperative approach to doing this:

```
def mark_list_on_condition(sequence):
    results = []
    for item in sequence:
        number = float(item)
        if number < 6:
            results.append('1')
        elif 6 < number < 10:
            results.append('2')
        elif number == 10.0:
            results.append('3')
    return results
```

**Sample Output:**

```
>>> print mark_list_on_condition(['8.3','10.0','1.0','8.7','6.9','4.7','8.7'])
['2', '3', '1', '2', '2', '1', '2']
```